# Admin panel for web application, how to make other modules hook into and extend the functionality

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a web-application where I am having a admin panel. I have built this application using Laravel. I have also extended Laravel with the "Caffeinated Modules" package, making it possible to have modules with their own individual controllers, views, models etc.

Now. I want the core and the base of all of it to be the "admin" module. The admin module should be the admin-panel of the application.

Now to my problem. I have trouble figuring out how to structure the application so that other modules can hook into the admin menu for example. And also how to make other moduels have their pages inside the admin panel which actually can handle the code being run. Basically how the other modules speak to the admin panel.

For example a Blog module should add add/edit/delete management of the blog posts. But I want all of the logic to be simply hooked into the admin module, so that the blog module (and all other modules) contain their own admin logic. A little bit similar to how WordPress or Magento works when you extend the CMS with plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Admin middleware (for your Routes) and then write your code as you want in any way. Just put URLs(Routes) that you need on admin panel inside the admin middleware.

**AdminMiddle**

> `namespace App\Http\Middleware;
>   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
>   use Closure;
>   class AdminMiddle
>   {
>       /**
>        * Handle an incoming request.
>        *
>        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
>        * @param  \Closure  $next
>        * @return mixed
>        */
>       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
>       {
>           if(Auth::user()->account->role!=="super_admin"){
>               return redirect('/access-denied');
>           }
>           return $next($request);
>       }
>   }`

Now put this middleware in your kernel.php

Please post the version of laravel, that you are using?

Put admin middleware on all the routes for admin panel and for normal user routes leave as it is (nothing to do)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am using the latest Laravel 5.3. You mean to use the middleware, and then each module will define it's own admin routes etc?

Comment: yeah, you want same page where users can login and access module on the basis of permission right?

Comment: If yes, then just create a module enum on DB dynamically and check those modules on routes, if the user has that module then the user will get that module. Similarly you can check on your view to whether to give access or not.

Comment: But if you only want to separate normal user and admin user and their modules then just create a MiddleWare (only one).